# Is there a way to plot conditional means in corner plot?

Tags: python, histogram

I'm working with three datasets in python, and with those I plan to make a [corner plot](https://github.com/dfm/corner.py), but I wanna be able to plot conditional means, just like the quantiles option showed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXZsf.png), but I'm not sure how to do this, any insight will be apretiated.

Edit:
Here is part of my code (assuming that every file has the same prefix, and the number of variables is provided)

> ```
>        truths = np.array([ 0.5, 1.4 ,2.0,  3.3, 2.6, 1.960])
> ```

```
        labels = [ "$f$" ,"$a$" ,"$Ks$", "$Kb$" ,"$N$","$rho$"]

        dimension = int(sys.argv[2])

        #get the shape of walkers
        test = np.genfromtxt( sys.argv[1] + str(0)+".csv" , dtype=float, delimiter=',')

        print "\n\nWalkers : "   , test.shape[0]
        print "Walks   : ", test.shape[1]

        sampler = np.zeros( ( test.shape[0], test.shape[1] , dimension )  )

        # read data
        for i in range(0,dimension):

            sampler[:,:,i] = np.genfromtxt( sys.argv[1] + str(i)+".csv" , dtype=float, delimiter=',')
        #10 percent burnout
        burn_out = int( math.ceil( 0.1 * test.shape[1]) )

        print "burn out: ", burn_out
        print "\n\n"

        samples = sampler[:, burn_out :, :].reshape((-1, dimension))

        fig = corner.corner(samples, labels=labels[0:dimension], truths=truths[0:dimension] ,  show_titles=True, title_kwargs={"fontsize": 12} )

        fig.savefig("triangle.png")
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? Can you show data and part of your source code?

Comment: Here, I include a dataset to "play", which is an array of size 20x450, roughly every row of such array is a sample of a (unknown) distribution.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jznu627d3nqtqj/zdim0.csv?dl=0

Comment: And here is another one

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zsgx0rdqxr85ufo/zdim1.csv?dl=0